# How to ask user to fill out a short form after first log-in?

Tags: forms, login, registration, onboarding

We need to ask the user for additional mandatory information after their first log-in because we don't want to overwhelm them on the registration page. How do we do it so that it's not annoying.. and is it a common practice?

We are thinking of having a small pop-up welcoming the user and letting them know that there's an extra information that needs to be filled-out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask for the user's information at the time when they need to provide it. For example, don't ask for their shipping address until they're placing an order. Don't ask for their phone number until they ask for a phone call. Don't ask them to allow access to their camera until they click the "Take a Photo" control.

When these requests come in context, they understand the need for the request.

And, like @Scunliffe mentions, take a hard look at why you're asking for each piece of information. If it allows users to access a feature they're trying to use right now, then fine. If it offers users no benefit except to receive un-asked-for notifications from Marketing, then don't ask for it.

An occasional audit of the info you ask for will uncover pieces of user information that the company doesn't even use anymore. Get rid of those requests too!

Answer (score 4):

The language you use for this message will make a difference; show a popup with some cool message and an options like: **Complete your profile** and **Ask me later** buttons, and then analyze the button hit ratio - it will depend on the improtance of completing profile on the site.

Also, show a profile completion chart like LinkedIn does:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the user can't do anything without adding this info then take them straight into a welcome setup wizard to set this all up (eg like choosing your language and time zone on a mobile device first boot)

However if this is just stuff they will need to fill out in order to do something later... let them do it later. Eg if this is filling in my address so that if/when I want to ship something to my house I can do so.

Finally be very weary of what the user "needs" to fill in. If a technical requirement to continue, fine. If a legal requirement (signing acknowledgement etc.) fine, but if "Marketing wants this" or "Inside sales", "The analytics team", etc. wants this... be prepared to battle them on this as it is actually a "want" not a need. Some users will accept a painful login process if they deem the end goal worthy but many will see this as a sign of frustration and may reconsider you product/service... either way it doesn't set a good first impression.

Answer (score 0):

Also providing an incentive language and making a promise of improvement all into user's benefit later on might help, yes it's all about the copy and the language friendliness is a key element.